# Spring 3.1 HandlerInterceptor Not being called

Tags: java, spring

I followed the documentation for HandlerInterceptors.  Noting that in the new version of Spring: "the configured interceptor will apply to all requests handled with annotated controller methods".

The following is in an xml configuration file:
[image]

I have an annotated controller beginning like this:

[image]

When I request a url that executes the controller's code, my interceptor code is never called.  Can anyone please explain why?

The interceptor code is:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class DomainNameInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) 
         throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Why is this not called?");
    return true;
  }
}
```

I was using the following documentation:
[Spring Core 3.1.x Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

I did a search for HandlerInterceptor and followed the example given within the documentation in the included link.

Comment: Could you show the interceptor code? And please - no screenshots :)

Comment: You might also link the documentation you were following.

Comment: I have included the Interceptor code above.  Any ideas?

Comment: Good idea, I also included a link to the documentation.

Comment: Can you check the list of registered beans to confirm that the DomainNameInterceptor is actually being created by the framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have configured your MVC context using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`,then I think the handlerMapping created when defining beans based on this custom namespace is overriding the handlerMapping that you have defined. A better way to register your interceptors would be to use the `<mvc:interceptors>` subtag to define the interceptors, this way it will get registered to the correct handlerMapping:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <ref bean="interceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: This answer turned me in the right direction thank you!  I had forgotten I set up a Class using the @EnableWebMvc in my WebMvcConfig class.  The following ended up working:`@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Inject
 private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
     // Equivalent to <mvc:interceptors>
  registry.addInterceptor(new DomainNameInterceptor());
 }`

Comment: <mvc:interceptors> isn't a child tag of <mvc:annotation-driven> in Spring 3.1, but is now it's own root tag. Great answer otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

Biju's answer above is correct except in spring 3.1 you have to do this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
     <mvc:mapping path="/pathToIntercept/**" />
     <bean class="com.foo.bar.Interceptor" />
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old, but in case someone bumps into it looking for answers like I did, the use of a `MappedInterceptor` as described in the answer below worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948730/1705048