# Unit Testing I18N RESTful Web Services with Spring, RestTemplate and Java Config

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration

Trying to get Unit Tests to work when using Spring RestTemplate and I18N.   Everything in the setup works fine for all the other test cases.

Based upon what I read, this is what I put into the Java Config:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    return new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
}

@Bean
public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
    DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping mapping = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
    Object[] interceptors = new Object[1];
    interceptors[0] = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    mapping.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return mapping;
}

@Bean
public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
    return new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
}
```

Then in my usage with RestTemplate I have:

```
    public MyEntity createMyEntity(MyEntity bean) {
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    String localeString = "";
    if (locale != Locale.getDefault()) {
        localeString = "?locale=" + locale.getLanguage();
    }
    HttpEntity<MyEntity> req = new HttpEntity<MyEntity>(bean);
    ResponseEntity<MyEntity> response = restTemplate.exchange(restEndpoint + "/url_path" + localeString, HttpMethod.POST, req, MyEntity.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

While this could be cleaned up a bit, it should work - but the LocalChangeInterceptor never gets invoked.   I am debugging this now and will post again as soon as I figure it out - but in the hope this is a race condition that I lose - does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Was lucky and stumbled upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745736/spring-3-1-handlerinterceptor-not-being-called).  One of the notes clued me into the right direction.   You don't need all those beans in the Java Config.  But ***if you are using @EnableWebMvc*** as I am, but I didn't know it was important enough to even mention, all you need to do in your Java Config is:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    return new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
```

Add the one bean for the Interceptor and then override the method to add the interceptor.  Here my configuration class (annotated with @Configuration and @EnableWebMvc) also extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, which should be common usage.

This, at least, worked for me.  Hope it may help someone else.