# Spring MVC Interceptor pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have an interceptor that is supposed to intercept urls with different patterns like:

- myapp/something/add/whatever
- myapp/something/add
- myapp/something/addWhatever
- myapp/something/somethingelse/add
- etc...

I have to intercept all urls which contain "add". There are a lot of *somethings* and *somethingelses*...

I have tried different patterns but it seems that they are all wrong:

- **/add/*
- **/add*
- **/add/ ** (I added a blank space before the last ** so it doesn't format it to bold)

The interceptor is something like

```
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
}
```

I configure it in

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableWebMvc
class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {                       
        registry.addInterceptor(getMyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("**/add/*", "**/add/**", "**/add*");
    }

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor getMyInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }
}
```

If I try to access

http://localhost:8080/myapp/something/add/somethingelse

my interceptor doesn't intercept it...

Comment: Try `**/add*/**`  Here is the AntPathMatcher API page: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: Did you try `/**/add/**` and  `/**/add*`, because the path must be absolute.

Comment: You might want this `addPathPatterns("**/add*", "**/add*/**")` to include stuff that ends in "add"

Comment: Thank you sir, @DwB, I have read the API, it is really helpful. - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Here are my suggestions.

First use global interceptor and check the request uri:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();

        if(uri.contains("/add")){
            // do your job
        }

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

In my case, alls `add`- methods are `PUT`, or `POST` requests. So I'm checking this in my global interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String method = request.getMethod();
        if("PUT".equals(method) || "POST".equals(method)){
            // do your job
        }

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

configure it without `addPathPatterns`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableWebMvc
class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getMyInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor getMyInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can be fixed by Change the bean type to "Mapped Interceptor" and wrapping it; though people don't seem to know why its an issue in the first place.

Based on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948730/857994